# Why an absolutely positioned element inside centered relatively positioned div is not centered?

Tags: html, css

I can't understand why the following code does not make the image centered. Can you help me?

```
<div align="center" style="position:relative;">
  <div style="position: absolute">
    <img src="a.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: centered how? vertically? horizontally?

Comment: Why *should* it be centered?

Comment: @j08691 because it is inside a centered div, i suppose.

Comment: It won't unless you not define `left` and `right` property.

Comment: You've basically told it to be absolutely positioned to it's relative parent, that's a good start - but where do you go from there? If you're trying to get the absolute center you need to add ( top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; margin auto; ) to the absolutely positioned element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use auto margins and set `left` and `right` values if you want to center an absolutely positioned element.

```
#absolute-element{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/842cJ/)

Comment: My understanding is that an element which is positioned absolutely is positioned relative to its parent element. If the parent element is centered, then 0 top and 0 left of the embedded element is in the center. So then why is the image not in the center?

Comment: @Sunny88 I think you're referring to the `align` attribute inside of your outside div.  The `align` attribute only affects child divs that are not absolutely positioned

Answer (score 0):

You have to set top and left attributes when using absolute

Comment: Isn't the default value 0? It is positioned relative to the parent div, which is centered, so 0 top and 0 left should be in the center, shouldn't it?

Comment: 0 top and 0 left is top-left corner logically

Comment: Moreover align="center" is not supported in html5 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp

Answer (score 0):

To center the image horizontally and vertically add `left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; margin: auto;`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/D5m9G/1/)**

```
<div style="position:relative; height: 100%; background: #eee;">
  <div >
    <img style="position: absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; margin: auto;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want horizontally center then you have to define `left` and `right` property.

Have a look the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rakeregu/1/edit)**.

```
<div style="position:relative; border-top:1px solid red;">
  <div style="position: absolute; left:50%; right:50%;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. It means that the fact that i set align="center" on the div, didnt have any effect whatsoever?

Comment: Well instead of using `align="center"` would better you use `text-align: center` to center text element.

Comment: Downvoter please explain why giving `-1`? Don't know who you are but I am watching that last few days I am getting `Down Voting` for all of answers I've given in past. Moderators must look at this issue. Otherwise it would be good I should left `SO Forum.`